# How to check whether the set $S=\mathbb{R}-\{-1\}$ is a group under ‘$\star$’ defined as $a\star b =a+b+ab\ \forall\ a,b \in S$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to check whether the set $S = \mathbb{R}-\{-1\}$ is a group under the binary operation ‘$\star$’ defined as $a\star b =a+b+ab$  for any two elements $a,b \in S $ ?

Comment: Do you know what the group axioms are? Do you understand what it means to check them, in this context? Which ones have you tried, on which ones do you get stuck?

Comment: I have no idea to resolve this. I'm struck with this question.

Comment: @Jayashanka,Welcome to MSE! Most probably its your homework problem. Please show us your efforts!

Comment: You have to check the [Group axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition_and_illustration). First one : For any two elements in $a$ and $b$ in $S$, also the result of operation $a * b$ is in $S$.

Comment: This amounts to chech that if $a,b \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ -1 \}$ also $a*b=a+b+ab \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ -1 \}$. Obviously $a*b \in \mathbb R$; the only thing to check is that $a+b+ab \ne -1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group axioms are:

$(1)$ Closure under binary operation of the group i.e. $(a \star b) = c \in S \ \forall \ a,b \in S$.

$(2)$ Associativity of the operation '$\star$' i.e. for any $a,b,c \in S , (a \star b) \star c = a \star (b \star c)$.

$(3)$ Existence of identity of the group under $\star$ i.e. an element $e$ such that $(e \star a) = a = (a \star e) \ \forall\ a \in S$.

$(4)$ Existence of inverse under $\star$ i.e. an element $a^{-1} \in S$ such that $(a\star a^{-1}) = e =(a^{-1} \star a) \ \forall\ a \in S$.

Check that $S$ satisfies these properties with $\star$ as an operation.

Comment: Associativity!!

Comment: Thanks, I forgot!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. It is useful.